# Activity is crashing in api 19 and in api 25 it is showing abrupt behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

This is debug report inn api 19 emulator..

```
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                             at com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:42)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:42) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020068
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:36)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:157)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:153)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:42) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129) 
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:36) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:157) 
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:153) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:42) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 05-06 15:36:10.141 468-503/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '52947f70 com.example.admin.clicknorder/com.example.admin.clicknorder.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-06 15:36:10.141 468-503/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '52a636f8 com.example.admin.clicknorder/com.example.admin.clicknorder.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-06 15:36:10.141 468-503/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '52a783c8 com.example.admin.clicknorder/com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodList (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-06 15:36:10.285 5612-5612/com.example.admin.clicknorder E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
05-06 15:36:10.345 5612-5612/com.example.admin.clicknorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.admin.clicknorder, PID: 5612
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.clicknorder/com.example.admin.clicknorder.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.example.admin.clicknorder.Home.onCreate(Home.java:78)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

This is where error coming in fooddetails.java

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);
 database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 foods=database.getReference("Food");
```

This foodetail.xml activity file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodDetail"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="#0d0e0d"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
       >


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:title="Food Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCart"
    app:srcCompact="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nesterScrollView"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Food Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_price"
                        android:layout_weight="9"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1,000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/number_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    app:textSize="8sp"
                    app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:initialNumber="1"
                    app:finalNumber="20"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/food_description"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If any  more details will be required I'll edit my question.Thank you

Comment: what is your gradle dependencies?

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp`... Where is this file in your project? Which folders specifically?

Comment: res/drawable folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from log, you have troubles with drawable on FloatingActionButton with id `R.id.btnCart`

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020068 at 
...

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector at 
...

Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
```

Probably you made a misprint, and changing `app:srcCompact` to `app:srcCompat` will fix it

Comment: Thnx....it solved my problem but sir still it is not working fine..I  mean the image that should come on the top is not on the position..also the image scroll is not working..rest details scroll is working fine